# How do I determine the model organism from FASTA format

Tags: sequence, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

So I have this fasta format: For example

```
>sp|A9X7L0|ANMT_RUTGR Anthranilate N-methyltransferase OS=Ruta graveolens OX=37565 PE=1 SV=1
MGSLSESHTQYKHGVEVEEDEEESYSRAMQLSMAIVLPMATQSAIQLGVFEIIAKAPGGR
LSASEIATILQAQNPKAPVMLDRMLRLLVSHRVLDCSVSGPAGERLYGLTSVSKYFVPDQ
DGASLGNFMALPLDKVFMESWMGVKGAVMEGGIPFNRVHGMHIFEYASSNSKFSDTYHRA
MFNHSTIALKRILEHYKGFENVTKLVDVGGGLGVTLSMIASKYPHIQAINFDLPHVVQDA
ASYPGVEHVGGNMFESVPEGDAILMKWILHCWDDEQCLRILKNCYKATPENGKVIVMNSV
VPETPEVSSSARETSLLDVLLMTRDGGGRERTQKEFTELAIGAGFKGINFACCVCNLHIM
EFFK
```

So I am wondering how do I determine if one is:

```
 Bacteria
 Viruses
 Archaea
 Eukaryota
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anwser can be found when looking at the `OS` part of the header of your FASTA file. But suppose you don't have this information, then you would perform a [BLAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST_(biotechnology)) search. If the letters in your sequence would consist of only A, T, C and G it would be a DNA sequence. But since they are not you are dealing with a protein sequence. So we need to use [protein BLAST](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=blastp&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&LINK_LOC=blasthome).

Copy/paste the FASTA file in the online tool:

[image: BLAST search]

Leave the rest at the default settings and click on the BLAST button. After some time you will get the following results:

[image: BLAST results]

You will see that there is a 100% similarity match found with `Ruta graveolens` (as mentioned in the FASTA header) and around 80% similarity match found in `Citrus sinensis`.

If you want to know to which domain these species belong, you can click on the link to the accession records. For `Ruta graveolens` that is [A9X7L0.1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/A9X7L0.1?report=genbank&log$=prottop&blast_rank=1&RID=5TK0NDYA016). There you see that the common name of this plant is [common rue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruta_graveolens) which has the following taxonomy:

```
 Eukaryota; Viridiplantae; Streptophyta; Embryophyta; Tracheophyta;
        Spermatophyta; Magnoliopsida; eudicotyledons; Gunneridae;
        Pentapetalae; rosids; malvids; Sapindales; Rutaceae; Rutoideae;
        Ruta.
```